# To insert multiple rows in database (approx 100 in each column) after a condition becomes true

Tags: java, database, oracle, file

Below is my code :
In this all files from a folder a read one by one. In each file multiple keywords are searched. If the keyword is found then that is inserted into the database.

```
public class MyLogs {

    String folderPath="path to your folder";
    String filePath="";
    public void readLog() throws IOException{
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:dbName", "username", "password");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return; }   
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        Scanner sc = null;

        try {
            File folder = new File("path to your folder");

            for (File  file : folder.listFiles()) {
                if(file.isFile()){
                    filePath=folderPath+"\\"+file.getName();
                    String fileName=file.getName();
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                    sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
                    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                        String nextLine = sc.nextLine();

                        if (nextLine.contains("Status"))
                        {
                            String str=nextLine.substring(nextLine.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
                            String str1=str.split(":")[0].replace("\'", "");
                                String sql="INSERT INTO table"
                                    + "(columnName) VALUES"
                                    + "(?)";
                            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                            preparedStatement.setString(1, str1);
                            preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
                        }
                        if(nextLine.contains("row"))
                        {


                            String str = nextLine.split(" ")[0];
                        //  System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"+str);
                            String sql="INSERT INTO table"
                                    + "(columnname) VALUES"
                                    + "(?)";
                            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                            preparedStatement.setString(1, str);
                            preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
                        }

                            }
                }
            }
                if (sc.ioException() != null) {
                    throw sc.ioException();
                }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
            if (sc != null) {
                sc.close();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MyLogs ml=new MyLogs();
        ml.readLog();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your exact issue? it's not stated clearly.

Comment: I would suggest to find all Keywords first, putting them into a List of Strings and then build the values String after the Keyword "VALUES" like this: `String valueStr = String.join(", ", Collections.nCopies(keywords.size(), "(?, ?)"));` After that you can publish the Keywords into the PreparedStatement `int pos = 1; for (String keyword : keywords) { preparedStatement.setString(pos, keyword); pos++; }`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use insert all statement in this case I have made some changes in your code please try it.

```
    String folderPath="path to your folder";
          String filePath="";
           public void readLog() throws IOException{
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:dbName", "username", "password");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return; }   
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    Scanner sc = null;

    try {
        File folder = new File("path to your folder");

        for (File  file : folder.listFiles()) {
            if(file.isFile()){
                filePath=folderPath+"\\"+file.getName();
                String fileName=file.getName();
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
                 String sql="INSERT ALL ";
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    String nextLine = sc.nextLine();

                    if (nextLine.contains("Status"))
                    {
                        String str=nextLine.substring(nextLine.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
                        String str1=str.split(":")[0].replace("\'", "");
                             sql=sql+" INTO table
                                + "(columnName) VALUES"
                                + "(?) ";                    
                    }
                    if(nextLine.contains("row"))
                    {
                        String str = nextLine.split(" ")[0];
                    //  System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"+str);
                       sql=sql+" INTO table"
                                + "(columnName) VALUES"
                                + "(?) ";
                    }

                        }
                        sql=sql+" SELECT * FROM dual ";
                         PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
                   connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                        preparedStatement.setString(1, str);
                        preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
            }
        }
            if (sc.ioException() != null) {
                throw sc.ioException();
            }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
        if (sc != null) {
            sc.close();
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    MyLogs ml=new MyLogs();
    ml.readLog();
}
```